# Add image from java using fxml file created in scene builder

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

If I want to add image node to fxml (created in scene builder) file from java, how can I achieve this ?

```
private ImageView close;
private ImageView close;
Image i = new Image(“file:C:\\Users\\Tarun\\Desktop\\Close-icon.png”);
close = new ImageView();
close.setImage(i);
close.setFitHeight(20);
close.setFitWidth(20);
close.setX(570);
close.setY(10);
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(“table.fxml”));
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

I know that there is some method root.getchidren.add(close) but here I am not able to implement this method.

Comment: What is the problem with `root.getchidren.add(close)` ?

Comment: @gontrad 
When i try to write root.getChildren.add(close) then it gives me error msg that "get children has protected access in Parent".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast `Parent` to an appropriate class. E.g

```
AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(“table.fxml”));
root.getChidren.add(close);
```

Comment: This can't be the solution without a modification of the fxml file since the `root`is the same instance.

Comment: You just need to choose same layout class as one in fxml file

Comment: Also in most cases `Pane` will work as it's a parent for everything except Group.